# Write text on existing PNG with Node.js

Tags: node.js, image-processing

I'm trying to create a simple dynamic-badge (png) to embed in static pages to let know the status of my application.

I'd like so to use an existing PNG image and write on it some text with Node.js.
I've found lot of libraries but all of them use Imagemagick or Cairo as native dependencies, I'd like to avoid to install anything else on the server.

I've then found lwip, but I can't really understand how to write text on an image with it. How can I do?

Comment: As an alternative, would you consider wrapping the PNG in an SVG and add your text that way? My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24413133/batik-put-svg-on-top-of-image/24413676#24413676) shows the basics of this approach.

Comment: svg is not supported by old browsers so I don't think would be an enough cross browser solution...

Comment: I see your point. The question is then, how far back do you want to go in your browser support? PNG is not supported in old browsers either... You could also render the SVG back to PNG using e.g. https://www.npmjs.org/package/svg2png

Comment: yes but it's much more supported than svg

Comment: You're right, of course.

Answer (score 34):

You could use [Jimp](https://github.com/oliver-moran/jimp). It has a print method:

```
var Jimp = require("jimp");

var fileName = 'test.png';
var imageCaption = 'Image caption';
var loadedImage;

Jimp.read(fileName)
    .then(function (image) {
        loadedImage = image;
        return Jimp.loadFont(Jimp.FONT_SANS_16_BLACK);
    })
    .then(function (font) {
        loadedImage.print(font, 10, 10, imageCaption)
                   .write(fileName);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Comment: Or, it looks like everybody supports SVG these days: http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg

Comment: With Jimp you cannot write text with any size and color.

Comment: @dumitru You can.

Comment: Can we add a rectangular overlay on the top and text inside the overlay? with JIMP?

Comment: The limitation I have fount with Jimp is that you MUST use bitmap images and it is non-trivial to go from a ttf to a fnt file.

Comment: @VictorioBerra , you mentioned that ttf to fnt file is non-trivial . well, I am trying that from yesterday, and haven't been able to do it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529369/how-to-convert-ttf-to-fnt-with-fontforge 


I am following this link, but still no help.

Comment: Im also looking for custom Fonts and a Square Border around the printed words, as well as word wrapping. Anyone has a suggestion for the Square border?

Comment: Jimp is using 30% of my server CPU when trying to just place a text on the image. I've a 4 core CPU. If 5 users tries to run my code at the same time the server goes down.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a `ttf` file you can use `gm`
This will also align the text automatically so you don't have to keep track of your letter sizing / location.

```js
const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});


gm('path/to/image.png')
        .fill("#FFFFFF")
        .font("./font.ttf", 20)
        .drawText(15, 10, "your text", 'southeast') //can be any location
        .write("./output.png", function (err) {
            if (!err) console.log('done');
        });
```